# How to detect the current device and fire the correct event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, hover, mouseevent, device-detection

I am trying to detect the current device via jQuery Mobile and fire the correct event. So long so good...
The detection works fine but the hover/mouseover/vmouseover event will not work correctly (tap & click works fine)

**JS:**

```
(function(a) {
        (jQuery.browser = jQuery.browser || {}).mobile = /(android|ipad|playbook|silk|android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))
    })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);

    console.log('Mobile: ' + jQuery.browser.mobile);

    var menu = $('#menu-menue-1');
    var list = $('li', menu);

    menu.bind(jQuery.browser.mobile ? 'vmouseover' : 'tap', function() {
        list.fadeToggle(500);
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu-menue-1">
    <li>Menu Point 1</li>
    <li>Menu Point 2</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu-menue-1{
     display: none;
}
```

The Problem with my Long way Solution is that I need to write everything twice...

**Long Way Solution:**

```
if (jQuery.browser.mobile === false) {
        menu.hover(function() {
            list.fadeToggle(500);
        });
    } else {
        menu.bind('tap', function() {
            list.fadeToggle(500);
        });
    }
```

I tried vmouseover(jQM), mouseover, hover but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?
Thx in advance and sorry for my bad englisch.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
menu.vmouseover(function() {
    list.fadeToggle(500);
});
```

?

Comment: yea my solution now looks like this:
if (jQuery.browser.mobile === false) {
        menu.hover(function() {
            list.fadeToggle(500);
        });
    } else {
        menu.bind('tap', function() {
            list.fadeToggle(500);
        });
    }

but i thought i can have it more short/compact